# HTTP POST using urllib2

Tags: python, json, urllib2

IN the code below, I am trying to make a POST of data with urllib2. However, I am getting a HTTP 400 bad request error. Can anyone help me with why this might be the case? The URL is reachable from my computer and all relevant ports are open.

```
    data = {'operation' : 'all'}
    results = an.post(an.get_cookie(), 'http://{}:8080/api/v1/data/controller/core/action/switch/update-host-stats'.format(an.TARGET), data)
    print results
```

---

```
   def post(session_cookie, url, payload):
      data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
      req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
      req.add_header('Cookie','session_cookie=' + session_cookie)

      try:
        returnedData = urllib2.urlopen(req, data, timeout = 30)
        data = json.load(returnedData)
      except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.code
        print 'URL ERROR'
        return {}
      return data
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me:

```
import json
import urllib2
import logging 

def post_json_request(url, post_data, optional_headers = {}):
    """
    HTTP POST to server with json as parameter
    @param url: url to post the data to
    @param post_data: JSON formatted data 
    @return:  response as raw data
    """
    response = ""
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, post_data, optional_headers)
        jsonDump = json.dumps(post_data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, jsonDump)
    except Exception, e:
        logging.fatal("Exception while trying to post data to server - %s", e)
    return response
```

I'm using it in various stubborn platforms that insist to retrieve data on a specific method.

Hope it will help,
Liron